# Converting JSON to HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have an AJAX call that works perfectly and receives SharePoint List items as JSON. I want to populate the JSON object(s) to a printable HTML document, but I am unsure how to go about it because I don't want to post it to a table as that is not how I want the layout to look.

Here is my JS call to read from the list:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadData(source, url) {
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => r.json()) // parse JSON
    .then((data) => data.d.results) // unwrap to get results array
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((r) => (r.source = source)); // add source to each item
      return results;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("WeeklyReport1", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport1')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport"),
    loadData("WeeklyReport2", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport2')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport"),
  ])
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the JSON it returns:

```
{
   "d":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"random number string",
               "uri":"I removed this because it is a sharepoint link",
               "etag":"\"1\"",
               "type":"SP.Data.WeeklyReport1ListItem"
            },
            "Team":"Cowboys",
            "WeekOf":"2021-01-15T05:00:00Z",
            "OffensiveReport":"Insert something about the offensive report",
            "DefensiveReport":"Insert something about the defensive report",
            "SpecialTeamsReport":"Insert something about the special teams report"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Based on the JSON above this, this is how I want to place it in HTML but I have zero clue how to:

---

Cowboys(underline team name)

Offensive Report

- Insert something about the offensive report

Defensive Report

- Insert something about the defensive report

Special Teams Report

- Insert something about the special teams report

*If more than one team, insert next here*

To Reiterate my question. How can I take this object pulled from this loadData and populate it to an HTML Document in the format I demonstrated above?

**UPDATE: I UPDATED MY JS TO THIS JS WHEN IT POSTS IT IS SO SCREWED UP**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadData(source, url) {
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => r.json()) // parse JSON
    .then((data) => data.d.results) // unwrap to get results array
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((r) => (r.source = source)); // add source to each item
      return results;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("WeeklyReport1", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport1')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport"),
    loadData("WeeklyReport2", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport2')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport"),
  ])
  .then(([r1, r2]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="weekReport" style="width:100%"><thead><tr><td><strong>NFL Weekly Report</strong></td></tr>' +
        "<tr><td><strong>Team</strong></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td><strong>Offensive Report</strong></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td><strong>Defensive Report</strong></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td><strong>Special Teams Report</strong></td></tr>" +
        "</thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Team + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].OffensiveReport + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].DefensiveReport + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].SpecialTeamsReport + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      $("#reports").append(tableContent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="WeeklyReport">
   <table id='weekReport' style="width: 100%;">
     <tr>
       <td>
          <div id="reports" style="width: 100%"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

This is how it turns out:
[image]

Comment: use a template; either a js template string literal or a template tag with content placeholders that you replace().

Comment: @dandavis would you mind providing some more explanation, I looked it up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals and do not quite follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question. Since this is effectively using HTML to layout a template for some data, you could use a templating language like [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/):

Add Mustache.js to your page, add the `#target` element we will render to, and create a function to render the template to the page as HTML:

```js
/* 
 * Write the JSON data to a Mustache template and then
 * render the resulting HTML to the #target element.
 */
function renderData(data) {
  fetch('template.mustache')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(template => {
      const rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
      document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;    
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/4.1.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" ></div>
```

You can format the template however you want. Here's a basic one that lays out the text as you specified:

```
// template.mustache
<div>
  {{#d}} {{#results}}
  <div>
    <title style="text-decoration: underline"> {{Team}} </title>
    <p>Offensive Report</p>
    <ul>
      <li>{{OffensiveReport}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Defensive Report</p>
    <ul>
      <li>{{DefensiveReport}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Special Teams Report</p>
    <ul>
      <li>{{SpecialTeamsReport}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{/results}} {{/d}}
</div>
```

Mustache.js will automatically loop over the `d.results` array and create each HTML block for you.

If you do use Mustache.js, I strongly recomend you read the docs I linked above.

Comment: helpful example. my suggestion was basically this approach with native templates instead of mustache, but both are adequate solutions.

Comment: Aye, I didn't see your comment @dandavis (or OP's edits) until after I posted my answer but your native solution looks to work just as well! I hadn't considered using a templated string.

Comment: @James big fan of mustache after doing some research. Although, I cannot get it to work like I want it to. Creating a JSFiddle now

Answer (score 0):

The below response is a good, super general response for using Mustache. I like to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for this, which is way less of a general solution but (mostly) works. It's really easy to [plug json in](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) as the data source, and most of the defaults are really reasonable. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": r.json()
} );
```

} );

Comment: I know how to use DataTables, I didn't include it because as I mentioned in my OP, I do not want the format to resemble a table whatsoever. Thats why I said HTML Document, not HTML Table.